# Grails withForm and AWS interactions

Tags: grails, amazon-web-services, groovy

The following issue is using the following:

- AWS
- PostgreSQL
- Grails 2.3.3
- Redis

On our account creation page, we are having some REALLY obscure functionality with the Grails `withForm{}.invalidToken{}` closure.

Upon hitting the page for the first time, everything works fine. You can post back to the server fine as long as you do not leave this page.

Upon leaving this page, either through navigation links or logging off, returning to the page (Again through navigation links or logging on and heading there), we can no longer submit, it hits the invalidToken closure every time.

I know AWS is involved as we took the project and deployed it to local machines both with IntelliJ and Tomcat by itself and both work fine. This issue only occurs upon deploying the WAR to AWS. (This occurs both with local builds and automated builds. They work locally but not on AWS)

We have spent almost a week on this issue trying to figure out why this is occuring, and all we have to show for it is we know AWS is somehow involved, but that's as far as we have gotten.

Does anyone have any insight into what would be causing our session to act like this?

Comment: Is it returning a cached copy of the page with an old token in it?

Comment: The token correctly updates every time. To be perfectly clear, token caching is NOT the issue here.

Comment: To be more specific:

There's so little information on this closure. we aren't sure if something else might be happening under the scenes involving caching. The SYNCHRONIZER_TOKEN that shows up on the HTML page is unique each time, so that's not being cached (nor is the URI).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a LOT of searching about this issue, me and my team finally figured it out. Taken directly from our JIRA:

"This issue is caused by the implementation of tomcat-redis-session-manager used on AWS. As per their documentation (https://github.com/jcoleman/tomcat-redis-session-manager#session-change-tracking), there are "unintended consequence of hiding writes if you implicitly change a key in the session or if the object's equality does not change even though the key is updated." Specifically, the "useToken" implementation is Grails 2.3.8 is: "String generateToken(String url) { final UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID() getTokens(url).add(uuid) return uuid }" The combination of these native implementations are there for incompatible. 
The tomcat-redis-session-manager does support a manual dirty tracking mode by setting: RedisSession.setManualDirtyTrackingSupportEnabled(true); but this would require a forked build of SynchronizerTokensHolder in grails-core."